# Linking OrTools to my project using CMake on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, or-tools

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.20.3)

PROJECT(LMH VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# OR-tools
SET(BUILD_DEPS ON)
SET(USE_COINOR OFF)
INCLUDE(FetchContent)
SET(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
FETCHCONTENT_DECLARE(
        or-tools
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/or-tools.git
        GIT_TAG        master
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FETCHCONTENT_MAKEAVAILABLE(or-tools)

# Source files
SET(SRC
# ...
)

# Header files
SET(HEADER
# ...
)

ADD_LIBRARY(LMH STATIC
    ${SRC}
    ${HEADER}
)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(LMH PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Header  
    $ENV{Boost}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(LMH ortools::ortools)

# For VS, to maintain the current directory tree inside the Solution Explorer
SOURCE_GROUP(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${SRC})
SOURCE_GROUP(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${HEADER})
```

I get different errors during the configuration step, first some files are not created:

```
CUSTOMBUILD : error : unable to create file docs/javadoc/com/google/ortools/constraintsolver/SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_std__setT_operations_research__RoutingModel__VehicleTypeContainer__VehicleClassEntry_t_t.html: Filename too long [D:\MYPROJ\Test\Build\_deps\or-tools-subbuild\or-tools-populate.vcxproj]
```

then:

```
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision '6897c64dbf7d18b97d3563d28dc4820e3eb52022'.

Failed to unstash changes in: 'D:/MYPROJ/Test/Build/_deps/or-tools-src'.
```

and finally:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1576 (message):
  Build step for or-tools failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1716:EVAL:2 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1716 (cmake_language)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1923 (FetchContent_Populate)
  D:/MYPROJ/Library/CMakeLists.txt:26 (FETCHCONTENT_MAKEAVAILABLE)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried following the guide I found on the git step by step but I cant't seem to solve this, any ideas what is going on with my build?

Comment: the cmake generation creates paths that are too long for windows. There are supposed to be workarounds.

Comment: I tried both with `SET(CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX 260)` and also by changing the [windows maximum file path limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry) but I still get the same `CUSTOMBUILD` error (I made sure to delete the CMake cache and everything generated before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `stable` branch or `main` (our dev branch).

master was an old branch with doxygen in it which lead to windows can't git clone it `-_-` (file path too long)

note: now ref doc lives in in https://github.com/or-tools/docs